# FireFox doesn't display XML content whent I test my .asmx web service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, firefox

When I test operations in my web service (the "invoke" button), the XML result is not shown, but it is like a string. When I call it from Google Chrome, it gives me XML result...

Firefox was showing XML and it just stopped, but only when I test operations. The Service Description (the link on the main .asmx page) is showing a XML file of all operations on the web service and the result is in XML...

What seems to be the problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was [Avira Browser Safety](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/avira-browser-safety/) addon.

Once removed from installed Firefox addons, XML display worked like a charm.

Anyway, try starting Firefox in [safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) and check if XML result is ok.

If so, try disabling each addon in turn, until you find the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the HTTP header of the service description have a Content-Type : application/xml but not the call to your web service.

One way to check that would be to use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and try to add a Content-type field to the header of your call. (You can use a breakpoint to make it easier) Then you can see the real result.